# install multiple versions of gitlab in single server

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to install multiple GitLab versions in single server? I already have GitLab 5.0.1 installed and running and planning to install 6.8 on the same server, will there be any issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky :)
We have a [GitLab recipe](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/misc/multiple-instances) for that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue since the [gitlab requirements](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/requirements.md) can change and evolve from [5.0.1](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/ec1a37875d2be29835d0ac165db22a19ca269e38/doc/install/requirements.md) and [6.8](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/01799721dc6cbc1dbfbd72b2b0d5fc128ac03da9/doc/install/requirements.md).
6.8 seems to support Ruby 1.9.3 still (like 5.+ did), so it might work.

But the easiest way to install multiple instances would be to isolate them in a [Docker container](https://www.docker.io/), which is available on a (recent 3.10+) Linux, but also possible on a Mac or Windows, with a [Vagrant 1.6+](http://www.vagrantup.com/).
(See "[Vagrant: Docker-Based Development Environments](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-docker-dev-environments.html)")

Without that isolation, you need to ensure no resources are shared, which is what [that document](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/misc/multiple-instances) describes, as mentioned in [axil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137281/axil)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23951925/6309).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am planning to install it in separate linux servers, Can i install 6.8 directly as a fresh installation or should i install 6.0 first and then make an update to 6.8?

Comment: @user3586664 This would be necessary only if you were using the same database, in order to migrate properly the schema. But if your new instance uses a difference separate database, you can install directly a 6.8.